# CSS3 or jQuery/JavaScript animations,which one is more compatible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I know now CSS3 is a lot faster than jQuery, but I want to know how CSS3 is spread nowadays, is it wide-spread? I believe jQuery is better this way because, you can animate CSS2 with it as well, so older browsers show animation, but if there are only a few people using older browsers I don't think I should use jQuery, or maybe there is a solution that my app will recognize whether the browser supports css3 or not, and if not, it tries to run the animation with jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-detect-css-support-in-browsers-with-javascript/

Comment: You should check for HTML5 capabilities and use CSS3 as default with JQuery as fallback to be on the safe side. Also take a look at Modernizer.js (http://modernizr.com/) that takes care of these issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) lets you create CSS animations with classic jQuery syntax and can fallback to js animations on [unsupported browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions)

Basically the problem is IE < 10, so you could consider just using css animations with no fallback; animations can be considered progressive enhancement and not having them on some browsers doesn't jeopardize user experience that much.
On top of that IE<9 has poor javascript performance so the fallback js animations wouldn't be so pleasant anyway.

Comment: So it first tries with CSS3 animation?

Comment: yes it checks for browser's support -> http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/source/#section-8

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery if you want the most compatibility. A lot of people still use old browsers such as Internet Explorer 8, which doesn't have the CSS3 support.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Microsoft Internet Explorer 6 was the first fully Cascading Style Sheets, Level 1 (CSS1)-compliant version of Internet Explorer. Windows Internet Explorer 8 is fully compliant with the Cascading Style Sheets, Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS2.1) specification and supports some features of Cascading Style Sheets, Level 3 (CSS3). Windows Internet Explorer 9 and Internet Explorer 10 add even more support for many CSS3 modules.

Comment: That's why I hate IE, screws up everything.

Comment: Agree, for CSS3 Animation browsers compatibility check here http://caniuse.com/css-animation

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is supported provided you have the libraries included, but not all the animations CSS is supported by all browsers.

[CSS browser compatibly](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)